# Nightly builds on GIT

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to GIT and trying to run 'nightly builds'

We have got a release 'develop' in which we merge the 'features' that we develop.

Should my script do a 'git clone develop' at the end of everyday?  (or)
Should my script do a 'git clone develop' for the first time followed by 'git pull develop' from the next day onwards ?

Please advise me

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "nightly builds." Git is a revision control system, not a build system -- git doesn't know how to compile or deploy production code in any way.  That's the job of systems like [scons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons), [bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) or something like [rez](http://nerdvegas.github.io/rez/). That's not to say that your custom build suite will not utilize `git clone` to dynamically grab the latest source to build from (in fact, it probably should), but "builds" in the way they are typically defined are not git's job.

Comment: If however, you just mean automatically keeping your repo up to date, then yeah doing something like `git pull origin develop` might make sense depending on your workflow...

Answer (score 0):

You can sync you local clone using any way, just one note: every-day `git clone` of full repo is longer than `git pull` for getting only today's changesets

Comment: @Badger Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

A good way to update an existing clone for deployment or packaging purposes is not to use `git reset`:

```
git fetch develop
git reset --hard develop/master
```

This fetches the changes from the remote, and just *replaces* the whole working directory content with the version of the remote.

This has a big benefit over `git pull` because `git pull` actually performs a merge: And a merge can cause conflicts which require user input. But when you build your system, you usually want to build only the exact stuff that is checked in, so overwriting the old version with the current version makes a lot more sense.

Note that there are many existing solutions that solve the task of automated builds. There are various [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) tools, and especially [continuous integration solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software) that take care of the whole idea of building when you check something in. Most of these can be configured to not only build with every push/checkin (in order to test if the new revision still builds), but also to provide access to nightly (or otherwise configured) builds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that